# Ansible: Detecting in parent role when meta dependency role had change

Tags: ansible

I would like to make an ansible role that drops some credentials into /etc for a few services that are running.  Each service is slightly different and requires different mechanisms for restarting to pick up the new credentials.

Is it possible to have a meta dependency somehow communicate back up to the consumer/parent to trigger a handler to restart the services that depend on the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `listen` as explained here: https://medium.com/@george.shuklin/listen-feature-for-handlers-in-ansible-29183524c7e1

Comment: Ah!  I started ansible pre-2.2!